# How To Extract Only Text From Blog Post in Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, blogs, trim, laravel-8

- Laravel Version: 8.35.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.0

**Description:**
Before posting question here I tried to find this answer but couldn't find.
I have stored complete article with tags and images in a database table. Now I want to extract only text from that article.
I am Try To Extract from this code:

```
{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($list->article_content, 150, $end='...') !!}
```

The Result on Frontend is like this:

[image: Result On Frontend]

I Only Want To display only text from all article content like this:
[image]

How Can I Extract Only Text From Whole Article Content on Frontend?
Plz Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Using `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Thanks, It Work. I Try `strip_tags()` Before Posting But It doesn't work. Now it works.